# PHP Magento - redirect and send data via post without form

Tags: php, magento, redirect, post

I have 2 php page. I want to redirect page 1 (contains a data (ex. username)) to page 2 that only receive post data.

Here is received code in page 2 (not editable due to development):

```
if (!$_POST["username"]||$_POST["username"]=="Studio") $username="Studio".rand(100,999);
else $username=$_POST["username"];
```

I tried to use curl for my case, and not get the data I needed.

Here'e my code in page 1:

```
$src = "http://test.com/test.php"
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$src);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=".$title);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$this->_redirectUrl($src);
```

Comment: in order for `$username=$_POST["username"];` to work, you need to click SUBMIT button that places the username into the httprequest object. If you can't add it there, you can use cookies and store that data in cookies.

Comment: @Andrew I can't edit the page 2. so, data must send via post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using CURL with POST ?

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url); //set URL
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1); // make a POST request
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_vars);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

`$post_vars` can be something like `'lastname=smith&firstname=bill'`

Comment: Yes, I did. after write that code, then I redirect to page 2. No post variable i found.

Comment: How did you redirect? Usually if your'e doing a header redirect, you create a new request, thus loosing the POST

Comment: by $this->_redirectUrl($src); (in magento, its used to redirect to external url)